# WebBrowser работа через прокси

Tags: c++, c++builder, webbrowser

Привет, как заставить компонент WebBrowser(с++ builder) открывать веб страницы через прокси сервера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Настройки явно не задаются, этот контрол — просто окошко с Internet Explorer внутри.

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией [`UrlMkSetSessionOption`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms775125.aspx), чтобы переопределить текущий прокси. Для этого создайте экземпляр структуры [`INTERNET_PROXY_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa385148.aspx) с `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY` и передайте её в вышеуказанную функцию с аргументом `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY`.

[Пример на Delphi: Свои настройки Proxy в программе с TWebBrowser. Изменение в ходе выполнения](http://www.delphimaster.ru/articles/TWebBrowser.html).